# Google Font "Merriweather" Is not showing up in Chrome.?

Tags: html, css, fonts

At the top of my code I have:

< link href=" https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" >

And in my CSS I have:

font-family: 'Merriweather', ;

But it is not showing up. I'm not sure what the reasoning is. It seems so simple and yet nothing is working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the top of my HTML:

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "stylesheet.css" />

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

<title>Jesse | Personal Chef </title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Jesse Personal Chef">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Food, Chef, Wilmington, NC, North Carolina Food, In Home Chef, Personal Chef, Chef For Hire, Jesse,">
  <meta name="author" content="Cal & Jen T.">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>
```

This is my CSS, saved in as stylesheet.css:

```
<style>

/* HEADERS ~~~~~~~~~~ */

    h1 {
        font-family: 'Merriweather', ;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.7em;
        color: 000;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 2%;
        line-height: 40px;
        padding-bottom: -100px;
        margin: 2%;

    }

     .subtitle {
        font-family: 'Merriweather', ;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.04em;
        color: 000;
        font-weight: regular;
        margin: 1;
        line-height: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 60px;

    }


</style>
```

Thank you

Comment: You might need to provide more code, like your `CSS Selector`, as we dont know if this could work with the code provided. Try showing all code necessary to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One little fix needed:

Change this:

```
font-family: 'Merriweather', ;
```

To this:

```
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
```

The `serif` portion is the fail-over font in case it can't find Merriweather.

Test it in this snippet:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href=" https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    div {
      font-family: Merriweather, serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also just apply the `font-family` style to the `<body>` tag and all child elements will inherit that font-family.

Comment: That's great! Please Accept the answer by clicking the check-mark next to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check fonts link:

   - if you use `@font-face` rule check link to the folder with fonts and be sure that font files is present in this folder, also check fonts name in `@font-face` rule and in `font-family` they must be equal;
   - if you use CDN - check the link to the CDN;
2. Open Dev Tools in your browser(Ctrl(Command) + Shift + I) and in the tab Network check whether your font is downloaded or not: https://prnt.sc/r9x8ab;